# how to unregister Mac app help book

Tags: objective-c, macos, apple-help

I registered help book for my app, then in the following days, I updated the help book, but when I execute my app, the help book is still the old version, it's not updated, is there any way to unregister help book? or let it update?

Answer (score 8):

I've found a nice blog post that includes a script that clears help viewer's cache and restarts the help daemon.

http://macergun.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/dealing-with-help-viewer-cache.html

The script looks like this:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.help*
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.help*
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
killall helpd
defaults write com.apple.helpindexer IndexAnchors YES
```

Comment: This should be the top answer; the linked KB document is returning a 404, and can't be found anywhere it seems. Just running the commands in the Terminal (don't need to run the last one, as it will be run next time Help Viewer opens) works great in Lion and Mountain Lion!

Comment: `killall helpd` didn't seem to work for me on 10.10.3. All I needed to do, though, was trash the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.help*` as above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the cache: it involves deleting a couple of folders and restarting the help daemon:
See http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3335

Comment: The link's up now. It worked for me when I last tried to do it a few months ago. The gist is deleting `com.apple.helpd` from your ~/Library/Caches folder after quitting `helpd` if running.

Comment: It also mentions trashing the `com.apple.helpviewer` cache.

Comment: I don't know if this works in Lion, but it's the only answer, so it gets the bounty by default.

Comment: kb now dead, refer to Richard's answer

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you don't have any copies of your application with the old help book lying around.  If you do the Help Viewer will find and display the old help.